# shortest path (mod3=1) in a graph

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

the problem is this: I have an undirected graph and a vertex s and I need, for every other v (in V) to find the shortest path between s and v which its length mod3=1 if exist or "infinity" if doesn't.

I tried to do the same "trick" I used to find shortest even path in the graph [by making a bipartite graph G' and run BFS on it] - tried to copy the graph 3 times so the first one will be "mod0", the second "mod1" and the third "mod2" and then run BFS on it, but when I tried it on one example it didn't work.

a. is my idea good? should it work? (maybe I did something wrong)
b. if not - I would really appreciate some direction / hint on how to solve it ;-)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming we are referring to a graph without edge weights, since you did not mention them. We may be missing some additional information such as:

**runtime constraint**? It would seem odd if you werent given an upper bound on runtime.
**Shortest path which its length is mod3=1**? Does this mean that you want the shortest path *regardless* of its value for mod3=1 and then to figure out if that condition is true *or* that you want the shortest mod3=1 length path for any given vertex from s to v in V (I am assuming the latter)
**What is your output**? It *sounds* like you are simply sending back the path lengths, not the paths or an array of boolean values.

BUT going with what you have given us, and without plainly giving you the answer, I would argue that we don't need to create copies of the graph, per se.

Think about the relationship between a vertex and its neighbors, though, and how the modC changes between a vertex and its neighbors along a path. To make things simple, start out by considering only s and its neighbors as your graph.

As for your answer, your idea is not bad because you are thinking about the problem, but it is always good to understand *why* a solution does not work. I think for this problem it may be easier to figure out a feasible solution first and then revisit your answer later.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi
think you for your answer. indeed, my graph doesnt have edge weights.
in addition, about the mission information:
1. run time - "best you can find" 
2. Shortest path which its length is mod3=1 - your second assumption :-) 
3. for every v in V i need to return the paths length if exists or return "infinity" if he doesn't.  

i'll go and think about what you said regarding the relationships between the vertex and its neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good. Copy thd graph three times. Thee three copies will correspond to path lengths mod3=0, mod3=1, mod3=2.

Make the graph directed, with the following edges: if there is an edge between vertices a and b, add these directed edges: `a0->b1, a1->b2, a2->b0, b0->a1, b1->a2, b2->a0` where a0,a1,a2 are the three copies of a.

After that, you can use BFS to find edges between s0 and v1, so the length of the path will be congruent by 1 mod 3.